# Cookie doesn't work in Chrome only

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

This is a frequency cap cookie for a basic slide toggle, that I have not used in awhile. Works in FF, IE, does not work in chrome. The cap is based on calendar day, not 24 hour time period.

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var pageURL = location.href.toLowerCase();
var sbFirstSlide = (document.cookie.indexOf('sbb_'+pageURL) == -1); //check cookie for 'already seen today'
var sbTrigger = jQuery('#slidebartrigger');
var slideState = 0;     //0=up, 1=down
var downTM, upTM;
function slideUp(){
    if(slideState==1){
        if(downTM) clearTimeout(downTM);
        jQuery("#slidebar").slideToggle(200);
        slideState=0;
        sbTrigger.removeClass("closeSlide").one('click', slideDown);
    }
}   
function slideDown(){
    if(slideState==0){
        if(upTM) clearTimeout(upTM);
        jQuery("#slidebar").slideToggle(500);
        slideState=1;
        sbTrigger.removeClass("firstSlide");
        sbTrigger.addClass("closeSlide").one('click', slideUp);
    }
}
function setSBBCookie(){
    var oneDay = new Date();
    oneDay.setUTCDate(oneDay.getUTCDate()+1);
    oneDay.setUTCHours(0, 0, 0, 0); //set to literally day-by-day, rather than 24 hours
    document.cookie="sbb_"+pageURL+"=true;path=/;expires="+oneDay.toUTCString();
}
if(sbFirstSlide){
    slideDown();
    setSBBCookie();
    downTM=setTimeout(slideUp,3000);
}else{sbTrigger.removeClass("firstSlide").one('click', slideDown);}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are probably running into is that Google Chrome doesn't allow you to set cookies when you run a local file. So, your line:

```
document.cookie="sbb_"+pageURL+"=true;path=/;expires="+oneDay.toUTCString();
```

won't work in Chrome when run from a local file. You will need to run your code from a server of some sort or use something like JSFiddle.

If you try and run your code on a webserver such as JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/X9yze/, you will see that it is setting the cookie in Google Chrome.

Comment: The reason you have had to put "Hope this helps" as code is... Because you are supposed to provide code! Link-only answers are not acceptable.

Comment: @AshleyMedway Do you have a suggestion for the code to post? I merely copied his code and pasted it into jsfiddle.

Comment: if it is the same code then there is no need to provide a fiddle in your answer, That makes this answer a comment. Not an answer.

Comment: @AshleyMedway The point of the fiddle is to prove that the cookie is being set by providing a web based version of their code so that they can see that the cookie is being set when run on a web server. It is an answer because it shows what their problem is and how to fix it. Isn't that the point? ~Also... it is not a "link only" answer. the answer is that "google chrome does't allow you to set cookies from a local file."

Comment: @AshleyMedway I don't see a question being asked in the original post. But from the edit it looks like Joseph was right. Google Chrome doesn't set cookies when you use a local file (file://).